# Why do bitmaps stay in memory unless I call GC.Collect?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I'm developing an application that connects to a GigEVision camera, and pulls images from it. I'm currently using the Pleora eBus SDK with C#.NET.

The code below is just a test application for the camera connection - it can stream images, but rapidly runs out of memory unless I call GC.Collect();
It's worth noting the images being streamed are large (4096x3072), so the crash happens fairly quickly.

I suspected at first that not calling Dispose() was the issue. However, I can call Dispose() on each image right before getting rid of the reference to it, and that did not fix the issue.

I've also tried explicitly releasing the buffers that come into the display thread callback, but that had no effect.

Can I get my memory back in a more elegant way?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PvDotNet;
using PvGUIDotNet;
using System.Drawing;

namespace eBus_Connection
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        PvDeviceGEV camera;
        PvStreamGEV stream;
        PvPipeline pipeline;
        PvDisplayThread thread;

        bool updating = false;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PvDeviceInfo info;

            PvDeviceFinderForm form = new PvDeviceFinderForm();
            form.ShowDialog();

            info = form.Selected;

            camera = PvDeviceGEV.CreateAndConnect(info) as PvDeviceGEV;
            stream = PvStreamGEV.CreateAndOpen(info.ConnectionID) as PvStreamGEV;
            pipeline = new PvPipeline(stream);

            if (camera == null || stream == null)
                throw new Exception("Camera or stream could not be created.");

            camera.NegotiatePacketSize();
            camera.SetStreamDestination(stream.LocalIPAddress, stream.LocalPort);

            camera.StreamEnable();

            camera.Parameters.ExecuteCommand("AcquisitionStart");

            pipeline.Start();

            thread = new PvDisplayThread();
            thread.OnBufferDisplay += thread_OnBufferDisplay;

            thread.Start(pipeline, camera.Parameters);

            status.DisplayThread = thread;
            status.Stream = stream;
        }

        void thread_OnBufferDisplay(PvDisplayThread aDisplayThread, PvBuffer aBuffer)
        {
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap((int)aBuffer.Image.Width, (int)aBuffer.Image.Height);
            aBuffer.Image.CopyToBitmap(b);
            BeginInvoke(new Action<Bitmap>(ChangeImage), b);
        }

        void ChangeImage(Bitmap b)
        {
            if (PictureBox.Image != null)
                PictureBox.Dispose();

            PictureBox.Image = b;
            GC.Collect();//taking this away causes memory to leak rapidly.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `PictureBox.Image.Dispose()`, not `PictureBox.Dispose()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that somewhere in your code an `Image` such as a [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) is not being disposed. `Bitmap` extends `Image` which implements `IDisposable` which means you need to call `Dispose()` on it when you're done with it (often by wrapping it with a `using` statement). You aren't disposing the `Bitmap` or `Image` somewhere so the GC finalizes it when it can (or in this case when you explicitly invoke the GC).

Once the GC determines that a class is no longer referenced, it becomes available to clean up... Before cleaning it up, it checks for a finalizer. If a finalizer exists, the class is placed in a special GC finalizer queue that will run the finalizer before cleaning up the resources/memory. Most `IDisposable` classes have finalizers which allow the GC to do the `Dispose()` call work in case you forgot to manually dispose the class yourself. It seems that this is what is happening to your code, but without seeing ALL classes I can only guess what isn't disposed (and no idea where).

**EDIT:** I do have a guess though. I bet the `PictureBox.Dispose()` call does not dispose `PictureBox.Image`

Comment: It is a missing Dispose() - as @MichealLiu pointed out, this line PictureBox.Dispose(); should be PictureBox.Image.Dispose(). I just couldn't see it on my own for some reason.

Comment: I was having the same problem, but it was due to a Graphics object. Hey guys, always use "using" statement! :)

Answer (score 0):

If an object implements `IDisposable` then you should absolutely call `Dispose` on it but disposing an object doesn't release the memory it occupies.  It releases things like, in this case, an image handle.  Such resources have to be released first, before memory can be reclaimed, so disposing still helps.

When the GC runs, if an object hasn't been disposed then it must first finalise it, meaning that it must wait longer to reclaim the memory.  If the object has been disposed, memory is reclaimed as soon as the GC runs.

The GC runs in the background though.  If your application is busy allocating more and more memory then the GC never gets a chance to run and reclaim it, regardless of whether you dispose objects or not.  In such cases, you need to invoke the GC explicitly from time to time.  Creating multiple images is the most common scenario that requires explicit GC invocation.

It's worth noting that ALL objects remain in memory until the GC runs and cleans them up, whether the object implements `IDisposable` or not.  You normally don't notice it though, because most apps have enough down-time to allow the GC to run implicitly and reclaim that memory.  There's nothing special about your `Bitmap` objects in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You are disposing the picture box instead of the image. Even if that will dispose the image in the picture box, it will only do that the first time. After that the picture box is in a disposed state and calling `Dispose` again will do nothing.

You should get the image reference from the picture box and dispose it once it's not used any more:

```
void ChangeImage(Bitmap b) {

  Image oldImage = PictureBox.Image;

  PictureBox.Image = b;

  if (oldImage != null) {
    oldImage.Dispose();
  }

}
```

A bitmap that isn't disposed correctly have to be finalized before it can be collected. There is a background thread that finalizes objects that needs to be collected, but if you abandon objects faster than that thread can take care of them, you will run out of memory.

When the bitmap is disposed correctly, it becomes a regular managed object that can be collected right away whenever the garbage collector wants to.